# Decrypt Function in Postgres - Cannot produce result in clear text

Tags: postgresql, encryption

Using AES-ECB encryption, I can encrypt values to and from python / django in and out of postgres. I know CBC is better, but the database is encrypted at rest and this is only to obfuscate for certain employees.

Here is the encryption method in python:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
import base64

enc_secret = AES.new(settings.AES_KEY.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_ECB)
cipher_text = base64.b64encode(enc_secret.encrypt(pad(value.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size)))
```

When it encrypts a sample email address, I get this value in the database:

[image]

I notice it says email (Text) in the column header, but it's stored as a bytea field

If I write this in postgres, I get the cleartext value no problem:

```
select decrypt(decode('vqRkrhUW9ze4Id0qSYHg0g==','BASE64'),'key','aes-ecb')
```

If I try to decrypt by calling the column name, I get this error:

```
select
    email, decrypt(decode(email::text,'base64')::bytea,
        'key',
        'aes-ecb')

    from table

[22023] ERROR: invalid symbol "\" while decoding base64 sequence
```

What am I doing wrong with the encoding and decoding?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the Base64 Encoded text to the database, I decode the cipher_text and instead insert the (hex?)...not sure what this is called.

```
        enc_secret = AES.new(settings.AES_KEY.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_ECB)
    cipher_text = base64.b64encode(enc_secret.encrypt(pad(value.encode('utf-8'), AES.block_size)))
    raw = base64.b64decode(cipher_text)
    return raw
```

Now, the value is stored as this and I dont have to decode in postgres before I decrypt.

```
0xBEA464AE1516F737B821DD2A4981E0D2
```